# Exists such thing as mozrepl for Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Looking for an Safari extension (or plugin) what acts as [mozrepl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mozrepl/), what works like a charm. :)

- Exists such thing?

If not, is possible somewhat easily control Safari ***from external scripts*** (perl, python, bash)? With control mean:

- `GET` urls (mean http GET method) - Via safari (e.g. the Safari will send the auth, session cookies, referere and so on).
- get source of the page (**after** the Safari renders all ajax calls and such)
- `POST` via Safari (for example using AJAX - but initieted from teh external script)
- etc...
- in short like: "mozrepl" :)

Seems, here is nothing comparable yet. I didn't delete the question, is someone found such thing - please add an answer.

*<sub>Ps: i know, how to use `curl` or like tools, but this isn't helps for e.g. grabbing a content of pages, where Safari managing the session authentication, cookies, referrers , user-agent strings and so on. Everything is rev-engineerable, but it is much easier to use a tool like `mozrepl` as doing the fullstack rev-engineering for getting scriptable web-sessions...)</sub>*

Comment: Try applescript

Comment: @Mark It is not exactly an Safari Extension or plugin, but can you please be more chatty and show me _how to do it_ in the answer? Would be happy accept it. Thanx in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the main idea is scripting Safari, I would try using Automator before trying AppleScript. I'd start by hitting the record button and then:

- Open Safari
- Navigate to your webpage
- `GET` by saving the webpage source
- Allow the page to do whataver AJAX calls you may want it to do

  - save the webpage source again
- Fill out a form, hit submit for your POST

  - save the webpage source yet again

Or you could try AppleScript with something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
    set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.example.com"})
    end tell
end tell
```

You can add to the script form fills and submit buttons with javascript:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('field').value = '" & myvalue & "'"
do JavaScript "document.forms[\"form\"].submit();"
```

I'd try this out within the JavaScript console within a web browser first to make sure you have the names of everything correct.

Comment: thanx for the answer - i'm looking for how to achieve scriptable safari using external scripts (Terminal.app & command line = e.g. bash/perl/python...